# Add custom users with a specific attribute to the 'friends' list

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter, django-custom-user

I have implemented the logic of adding users to the 'friend list' from the whole list of users.

**models.py**

```
class VendorList(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    @classmethod
    def add_vendor(cls, current_user, new_vendor):
        vendor, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        vendor.users.add(new_vendor)

    @classmethod
    def remove_vendor(cls, current_user, new_vendor):
        vendor, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        vendor.users.remove(new_vendor)
```

**views.py**

```
class VendorListView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'event/vendor_list.html'

    def get(self, request):
        #form = EventItemModelForm()
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        vendor = VendorList.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
        vendors = vendor.users.all()

        args = {
            #'form': form, 
            'users': users, 'vendors': vendors
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

def change_vendor_list(request, operation, pk):
    vendor = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if operation == 'add':
        VendorList.add_vendor(request.user, vendor)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        VendorList.remove_vendor(request.user, vendor)
    return redirect('/vendors/')
```

It works and provides the list of all users whom I can add to the list. However, I need to filter this 'whole' list and display only users who have **is_vendor** attribute (similar to is_staff).
Where should I filter users, in models or views? I have tried

```
vendors = vendor.users.filter(is_vendor=True)
```

which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that there is a list of available choices for filtering. Instead of filtering **is_vendor** I need to use **vendor** like this:

```
vendors = vendor.users.filter(vendor=True)
```